# issues with installing some dependencies for a golang script

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric

while  i m installing some depedencies for a golang file
this error apears

```
Vendoring Go dependencies ...
~/blockchain/FabricNetwork-2.x-main/artifacts/src/github.com/fabcar/go ~/blockchain/FabricNetwork-2.x-main
go: github.com/hyperledger/fabric@v2.1.1+incompatible: missing go.sum entry; to add it:
    go mod download github.com/hyperledger/fabric
go: github.com/hyperledger/fabric@v2.1.1+incompatible: missing go.sum entry; to add it:
    go mod download github.com/hyperledger/fabric
~/blockchain/FabricNetwork-2.x-main
Finished vendoring Go dependencies
```

Comment: Always try `go mod tidy` to clean up the module dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears because your go package manger didn't created the **go.sum** file, that contain the package checksums. 
Have you tried to run `go mod download github.com/hyperledger/fabric` as metioned in your message?

```
missing go.sum entry; to add it:
go mod download github.com/hyperledger/fabric
```

I hope this help :) 
Regards.

Comment: i ve already tried to run the command but this what appears :cannot match "github.com/hyperledger/fabric" without -versions or an explicit version: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory